# ASP.NET Mixed authentication IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis, mixed-authentication

I'm trying to create an application that mixes windows authentication with forms authentication. The idea is simple: whenever the browser is able to use NTLM and the user has permissions, then he should be automatically logged in. When that doesn't happen, the user must be redirected to a page that shows a login form. I've found an old article (http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/) and I've also found a sample online (https://github.com/patuww/P2000DemonstrationProjects/tree/master/MultiAuthExample) which should be able to solve my problem.

Unfortunately, it's not working and I was wondering if there's any more info about this.

Thanks.

Luis

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I have just asked what I think is very similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154992/asp-net-web-api-2-and-mixed-authentication-using-both-integrated-windows-and-tok).

Comment: Unfortunately, not...